# Why will this Swift code crash in playground?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I'm following a tutorial which draws an image in playground. It really confuses me that the following code just crash:

```
import UIKit

let size = CGSize(width: 120, height: 200)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0)

let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

let darkGoldColor = UIColor(red: 0.6, green: 0.5, blue: 0.15, alpha: 1.0)
let midGoldColor = UIColor(red: 0.86, green: 0.73, blue: 0.3, alpha: 1.0)
```

After several tests, I'm pretty sure **UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()** has something to do with this problem. After I comment out that line, the code just runs. But it is really weird if I just only comment out the last line, the code also runs. Can someone helps me with this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The code doesn't actually do anything, though I do note that it doesn't seem to "complete" in Playground - but it doesn't crash. I added some actual drawing code, and it seems to work without changing your code...
`CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, darkGoldColor.CGColor)


CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size))
let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`

Comment: @Grimxn Thanks! I found that if I just keep typing other codes the program just compile again... I assume playground has some mystic mechanisms : )